# Should a RESTful API return different status codes or error messages for token expired and unauthorized?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, authentication, restful-authentication

I am developing a RESTful API using authentication tokens.

The workflow is simple; the client does a /getAuth request, sending user credentials, which returns a token for that user.

The user then passes the token in all the following requests to the API as an header. After some time/ number of calls (decided by the server) the token expires. When a request with an **expired token** in its headers reaches the server, the response status is **401 Unauthorized**.
In that case, the user must **ask for another token** with /getAuth, and so on.

The problem I am facing is that when a request is unauthorized for any other reason (accessing an unauthorized resource), the API also returns 401 Unauthorized. At this point, the client cannot know if it is trying to access something he cannot access, or if its user token is expired. Without any way of knowing that, it would ask for a token again, and replay the same request, thus getting a 401 again and so on.

So my question is : *should a RESTful API return a different status code, or  error message, for an expired token than the status and error returned for an unauthorized request, or should the client find some way for managing that* ?

The solution I found client-side would be to save each request url and not retry a request which fails with a fresh (just received) token. But I think its very dirty.

Comment: You can return AccessDenied for the routes that user does not have access to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the token expired, the client is no longer authorized, so returning a `401 Unauthorized` header makes sense.

> The problem I am facing is that when a request is unauthorized for any other reason (accessing an unauthorized resource), the API also returns 401 Unauthorized. At this point, the client cannot know if it is trying to access something he cannot access, or if its user token is expired.

If the (*authorized*) client tries to access a resource and doesn't have proper privileges, you should return `403 Forbidden`.